# PHP script: How big is too big?

Tags: php, linux, filesize

I'm developing a webapp in PHP, and the core library is 94kb in size at this point.  While I **think** I'm safe for now, how big is too big?  Is there a point where the script's size becomes an issue, and if so can this be ameliorated by splitting the script into multiple libraries?

I'm using PHP 5.3 and Ubuntu 10.04 32bit in my server environment, if that makes any difference.

I've googled the issue, and everything I can find pertains to PHP upload size only.

Thanks!

---

Edit: To clarify, the 94kb file is a single file that contains all my data access and business logic, and a small amount of UI code that I have yet to extract to its own file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean you have 1 file that is 94KB in size or that your whole library is 94KB in?

Regardless, as long as you aren't piling everything into one file and you're organizing your library into different files your file size should remain manageable.

If a single PHP file is starting to hit a few hundred KB, you have to think about why that file is getting so big and refactor the code to make sure that everything is logically organized.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was about to say. The big issue here is code organisation.

Comment: depends as well on how much is loaded per request. If you have 100 files that are all included or 100 files where only certain files are used depending on the request.

Comment: Yeah, but if you have a PHP file that is very big then you're likely not splitting up your code into more digestible chunks. It becomes easier to maintain as well, I think

Answer (score 2):

I've used PHP applications that probably included several megabytes worth of code; the main thing if you have big programs is to use a [code caching tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator) such as [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) on your production server. That will cache the compiled (to byte code) PHP code so that it doesn't have to process every file for every page request and will dramatically speed up your code.